# Efficient read and write in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-design, database, database-normalization

I have a mysql table which stores a set of queries (strings).

The table with its contents looks like this :-

```
query_id   queryString
  1.         Query 1
  2.         Query 2
  3.         Query 3
```

The results table which are somehow related to the above mentioned queries are stored in a different mysql table in the form shown

```
result_id   query_id  resultString
   1.           1      Result 1
   2.           1      Result 2
   3.           2      Result 3
   4.           2      Result 4
   5.           2      Result 1
   6.           3      Result 3
   7.           3      Result 4
   8.           3      Result 5
```

Clearly, the model above has redundancy, as I have to store **Result 1** , **Result 3** and **Result 4** more than once. This redundancy further increases with increase in number of similar queries. So, lets say if I have to do some processing on the results query, I would have to do on several duplicate values.

In another alternative which I can think of is that I can store results uniquely in a table and store the results_id to which they refer along with the queries in the query table. But in that case, while reading results for a query, I would have to hit a number of mysql queries, one corresponding to every result_id that I have. So, that seems inefficient(w.r.t read) to me.

What other possible solutions could help me in removing redundancies with minimal increase in the read/write load ?

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a N:N relationship between querys and resultstrings so :

You need for Querystrings like the one you already have.
Create another table for resultstrings and create another one to link querystrings and resultstrings. Dont forget foreign keys.

Comment: But, they are not unique. Thats what I mentioned in the example. Ex - Result 1 is there for both Query 1 and Query 2

Comment: but the combination of the two values is in fact unique.. in a relational point of view your table is OK.

Comment: Yeah, but I wish to remove redundancy anyhow as the processing on them is very costly

Comment: if the data is actually correct, i don't see why you should remove it

Comment: there is no way you can put this data in another better way. If information is redundant, why store it ?

Comment: The result string actually has a set of attributes which changes daily  and the update process is something which is very costly. So, doing that again and again is becoming almost impossible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39150/discussion-between-prashant-singh-and-jonysuise)

Comment: for relations N:N like the one you are describing, the best solution is to create a table for resultstrings and another for querys, and a third one to link the two.

Comment: Yeah, but that would increase the number of mysql queries I have to make to retrieve the complete list of results ! I would have to read all the relations from the table and then read each result individually